# Using PHP to show username and login status check

Tags: php

I've searched through StackOverflow for my problem and found some answers, but they are too specific. Basically I want two things. First, to be able to show the current user's username anywhere on my page with a simple call. Second, to check if the user has been logged in and if not redirect him to the login page. For example, he wants to access the shop card, but since he is not logged in, he should get redirected. Here is my code:

**login.php - controller**

```
<?php

$tpl = 'login';

if (!empty($_POST['login'])) {

$user = $DB->query('SELECT id FROM users WHERE user_name=' . $DB->quote($_POST['login']) . ' AND password=MD5("' . $_POST['password'] . '")')->fetch();
if (!empty($user)) {
    $_SESSION['uid'] = $user['id'];
    header('Location: /');
} else {
    $error = 'incorrect password';
}
}
```

**login.php - main page**

```
<br>
<a href="/register">Registration</a>
<br>
<form class="form-horizontal login col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-3" role="form" method="POST">

<?php
if (!empty($error)) {
    echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">' . $error . '</div>';
}
?>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Логин</label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" name="login" value="<?= @$_POST['login'] ?>" placeholder="Insert login" autocomplete="off">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Пароль</label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="Insert password" autocomplete="off">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-3">

    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Enter</button>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: You should definitely learn about input sanitation/validation if you don't want to get hacked -- `filter_var` is a good place to start, but PDO's prepared statements are the other half to that -

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the user logs in, save their screename to the session:

`$_SESSION['login'] = $_POST['login']`

and then, to put his username on any page, you can just

`echo $_SESSION['login']`  - or : `<?=$_SESSION['login']?>`

To use `$_SESSION`, you have to declare `session_start();` beforehand... before anything is output to the browser.

Then, to redirect un-authenticated users, you can just:

```
if(!$_SESSION['login']){
     header("Location: http://loginpage.com");
}
```

Comment: remember to sanitize user input and have `session_start` before anything is output to the browser

Comment: Should I declare it in login.php? Or do I need to use it wherever I use $_POST? Should I declare it in an .html file by using <? PHP in the beginning?

Comment: Sanitizing user input is outside of this scope, but I will modify this answer according to your second point- I forgot about that -

Comment: If the file ends in `.html` - php cannot be rendered in it - but *anywhere* you plan to use `$_SESSION` - you have to call `session_start()` first --